# Website isn't pulling the user data from the database for a login

Tags: php, error-handling

It keeps giving me my else error of there not been a user when there is. Can you guys give a noob some help? It's driving me mad! I have tried changing the column names round and it hasn't seemed to of stopped the problem. Database connects fine.

```
    <?php
include("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 //Protect MySQL Injection
 $username=stripcslashes($username);
 $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($username);
 $username=htmlspecialchars($username);

 $password=stripcslashes($password);
 $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
 $password=htmlspecialchars($password);
 //Run Query to Database
 $sql="SELECT * FROM officers WHERE officer_username ='$username' AND officer_password ='$password'";
 $result=mysqli_query($sql);
 //Counting Numbers of MySQL row [if user Found row must be 1]
 $row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 //Fetching User Informaiton from Database
 $userinfo=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $role=$userinfo['role'];

 if($row==1){
  //Initilizing SESSION with Differents user Role
  $_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
  $_SESSION['role']=$role;
  if($role=='admin'){ 
  header('location:admin.php');
  }
  if($role=='user'){

  header('location:user.php');
  }

 }else{
  echo "No User Found by Given Information";
 }

}

?>
```

Comment: please do not go live with that query. You'll get hacked

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
  //Run Query to Database
   $sql="SELECT * FROM officers WHERE officer_username ='".$username."' AND officer_password ='".$password."'";
```